# Concatenation to urllib file name

Tags: python, urllib

I have a problem when if I try to concatenate an extension .jpg to a filename i'm getting a "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: " but saves fine without the extension.

```
url = "http://" + str(self.get_image())
self.path_root = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1] 
self.img_dir = str(self.path_root) + '\\static\\images\\newspapers\\' 

#This line throws a file not found error when I add the _ and .jpg 
self.fullfilename = '_'+ str(slugify(self.subheadline)) + '.jpg'
```

It was working before but I have this error narrowed down to adding and extension self.fullfilename is a string

```
#This line saves fine but I need the extension as it's an image
self.fullfilename = str(slugify(self.subheadline)) 


urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, self.img_dir + '_'+ self.fullfilename)
```

here is the stacktrace

```
 File "newspapers.py", line 271, in <module>
dw.save_image()
File "newspapers.py", line 149, in save_image
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, self.img_dir + self.fullfilename)
File "C:\Users\peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 257, in urlretrieve
tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'E:\\mydirectory\\images\\newspapers\\_pere-aragones- 
vicepresident-de-la-generalitat-defiende-que-la-politica-desplace-a-la-represion'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and I think its because you can't concatenate within the urllib.request.urlretrieve even though it did before.

Solution:

```
path 1 → self.img_dir = str(self.path_root) + '\\static\\images\\newspapers\\'
filename →  self.fullfilename = '_'+ str(slugify(self.subheadline)) + '.jpg'

self.sav_file_name = self.img_dir + self.fullfilename 

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, self.sav_file_name)
```